# How to refactor, (shorten) this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with tables: applicant (or candidate for a job), application (candidate applied for a certain job), test, selected_test(any application has a defined set of tests) and test_result.

When I need to show which applicant scored what result for any application and test I would use this query:

```
SELECT applicant.first_name, applicant.last_name, application.job, test.name, test_result.score 
FROM applicant 
INNER JOIN application ON application.applicant_id=applicant.id
INNER JOIN selected_test ON application.id=selected_test.application_id
INNER JOIN test ON selected_test.test_id=test.id
INNER JOIN test_result ON selected_test.test_id=test_result.test_id AND applicant.id=test_result.applicant_id
```

What I need to accomplish is sorting by certain test type (test.name) along with test.score

This is what I mean:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, app.job, iq.score AS iqScore, math.score AS mathScore, personality.score AS personalityScore, logic.score AS logicScore
FROM applicant a 
INNER JOIN application app ON a.id=app.applicant_id 
LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT app.id AS appId, tr.score 
FROM applicant a 
    INNER JOIN application app ON app.applicant_id=a.id
    INNER JOIN selected_test st ON app.id=st.application_id
    INNER JOIN test t ON st.test_id=t.id AND t.name='iq'
    INNER JOIN test_result tr ON st.test_id=tr.test_id AND a.id=tr.applicant_id) AS iq ON app.id=iq.appId

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT app.id AS appId, tr.score 
FROM applicant a 
    INNER JOIN application app ON app.applicant_id=a.id
    INNER JOIN selected_test st ON app.id=st.application_id
    INNER JOIN test t ON st.test_id=t.id AND t.name='math'
    INNER JOIN test_result tr ON st.test_id=tr.test_id AND a.id=tr.applicant_id) AS math ON app.id=math.appId

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT app.id AS appId, tr.score 
FROM applicant a 
    INNER JOIN application app ON app.applicant_id=a.id
    INNER JOIN selected_test st ON app.id=st.application_id
    INNER JOIN test t ON st.test_id=t.id AND t.name='personality'
    INNER JOIN test_result tr ON st.test_id=tr.test_id AND a.id=tr.applicant_id) AS personality ON app.id=personality.appId

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT app.id AS appId, tr.score 
FROM applicant a 
    INNER JOIN application app ON app.applicant_id=a.id
    INNER JOIN selected_test st ON app.id=st.application_id
    INNER JOIN test t ON st.test_id=t.id AND t.name='logic'
    INNER JOIN test_result tr ON st.test_id=tr.test_id AND a.id=tr.applicant_id) AS logic ON app.id=logic.appId

ORDER BY mathScore DESC, iqScore DESC, logicScore DESC
```

The query returns a set of applications, showing applicant data, job, test names and scores.

For instance, if I want candidate applications with higher "math" score, followed by highest scores in "IQ" and then in "logic" to be on top, 'ORDER BY' clause looks like the above.
The query works correct but the problem is that in real situation it deals with large data sets and I need a way to shorten/refactor this query.

Example database it works on is here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `applicant` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `applicant`
--

INSERT INTO `applicant` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
(2, 'Jack', 'Redburn'),
(4, 'Barry', 'Leon'),
(6, 'Elisabeth', 'Logan'),
(7, 'Jane', 'Doe');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `application`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `application` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`applicant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`job` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `application`
--

INSERT INTO `application` (`id`, `applicant_id`, `job`) VALUES
(2, 2, 'Salesman'),
(4, 4, 'Policeman'),
(6, 6, 'Journalist'),
(8, 6, 'Hostess'),
(9, 7, 'Journalist');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `selected_test`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `selected_test` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`application_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`test_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `selected_test`
--

INSERT INTO `selected_test` (`id`, `application_id`, `test_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(5, 2, 1),
(6, 2, 2),
(7, 2, 3),
(8, 2, 4),
(9, 3, 4),
(10, 3, 2),
(11, 4, 1),
(12, 4, 2),
(13, 4, 3),
(14, 4, 4),
(15, 5, 2),
(16, 5, 3),
(17, 6, 1),
(18, 6, 4),
(19, 7, 3),
(20, 7, 2),
(21, 7, 1),
(22, 8, 2),
(23, 8, 3);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `test`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'math'),
(2, 'logic'),
(3, 'iq'),
(4, 'personality');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `test_result`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_result` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`applicant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`test_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`score` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test_result`
--

INSERT INTO `test_result` (`id`, `applicant_id`, `test_id`, `score`) VALUES
(2, 2, 1, 6),
(3, 4, 1, 7),
(6, 6, 1, 3),
(7, 7, 1, 8),
(9, 2, 2, 15),
(11, 4, 2, 12),
(13, 6, 2, 11),
(14, 7, 2, 9),
(15, 7, 3, 105),
(16, 6, 3, 112),
(18, 4, 3, 108),
(20, 2, 3, 117),
(22, 4, 4, 70);
```

And here is what results look like:
First query is just to show you how data is related:

[image: First query is just to show you how data is related]

The large query, shows score data horizontally so it is possible to sort by test name and score:

[image: The large query, shows data horizontally so it is possible to sort by test name and score]

Comment: It would help if you show'd the results of your 2 queries but I think what you want to look at is to pivot the data

Comment: I just added images of results for both queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*caveat I don't know mysql*

Googling *mysql pivot* gives this result http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

So if we apply the same logic using the `test.id` as the seed number (which is *exam* in the example from the google search) we get this:

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd2d7/10)

```
select first_name, last_name, job, 
  sum(score*(1-abs(sign(testid-1)))) as math,
  sum(score*(1-abs(sign(testid-2)))) as logic,
  sum(score*(1-abs(sign(testid-3)))) as iq,
  sum(score*(1-abs(sign(testid-4)))) as personality
from 
(
    SELECT applicant.first_name, applicant.last_name, application.job, test.name, test_result.score, test.id as testid
    FROM applicant 
    INNER JOIN application ON application.applicant_id=applicant.id
    INNER JOIN selected_test ON application.id=selected_test.application_id
    INNER JOIN test ON selected_test.test_id=test.id
    INNER JOIN test_result ON selected_test.test_id=test_result.test_id AND applicant.id=test_result.applicant_id
 ) t
group by  first_name, last_name, job
```

Now you've got your short query yu can apply sorting as required - you can use `case` statement in you `order by` to dynamically change the order as required...

Comment: Ok, only 45 minutes took me to get it ;-D Works fine. Much obliged

Comment: @DjuroMandinic lol it took me 12 mins to post that answer (with working fiddle) from the point that you posted the question - and I don't do mysql (only ms/tsql) :D - it's a funny old world

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that you have only defined primary keys.  You should see a noticeable performance improvement when you index other fields.  Index at least the following: application.applicant_id, selected_test.application_id, selected_test.test_id, test_result.applicant_id, test_result.test_id, test_result.score.

You might be surprised how much this speeds things up for you.  In fact, mysql tells us this is the best way to improve performance: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html.

Comment: No doubt indexes would improve performance. However the main problem with the query IMHO is that it consists of repeating large chunks of text which differ only by the test name. There must be a better way to do it but I am missing it.